# How to ignore @click for bootstrapvue buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

```
<button  type="button" text="whateverText"    
   v-on:click="whateverFunction()">
  <fai @click="toggleShow()" icon="eye"></fai>
</button>
```

The icon is inside the button and clickable. If i click the icon, the button will be clicked too, how can i fire the icon event only (without the button event).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use this to stop the bubbling to the `button` tag.

```html
<fai @click.stop="toggleShow"></fai>
```

From the official docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: Thanks for your answer,in your link was @click.self explained: "only trigger handler if event.target is the element itself, and NOT from a child element".
With v-on:click.self="whateverFunction()" the child <fai> element doesnt trigger anymore.

Comment: Why do you not use `stop` as show in my answer..? Also, remove those parenthesis if you do not want the function to run when it loads.

Comment: Here is a hosted solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-colden-q1oq2?file=/pages/index.vue Click on "before" or "after" and it will fire the event from the parent. Click on "nice" and it will ONLY fire the child event thanks to `.stop`. As stated above.